# jQuery get checkboxes either checked or have a specific data

Tags: jquery, dictionary, checkbox, filter, selector

I have a form with many checkboxes, some of which have a specific data property (say `data-myname`). Now, on click of a button, I need to get the collection of checkboxes that are either `checked` or have the property `data-myname` (checked or not) and use inside `$.each(filteredCollection, function(){.....})`.

I looked at using .map and .filter, but due to my limited understanding of these functions, I am not able to get the right sequence of conditions to be used.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` and `...` spread operator to fetch multiple conditions.

```js
let el = [...document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]:checked"), ...document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox][data-myname]")]

console.log(el)

el.forEach(e => e.nextElementSibling.style.color="red")
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="1"  value="Bike" data-myname="">
<label for="vehicle1"> 1</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="Car" >
<label for="vehicle2"> 2</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="3"  value="Boat" checked>
<label for="vehicle3"> 3</label><br> 
<input type="checkbox" id="3"  value="Boat" data-myname="">
<label for="vehicle3"> 4</label><br> 
<input type="checkbox" id="3"  value="Boat">
<label for="vehicle3"> 5</label><br>
```

And if you want to use `filter`:

```js
let el = [...document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]")].filter( (e) => {
  if (e.checked || e.hasAttribute("data-myname")) {
    return e
  }
}) 

console.log(el)

el.forEach(e => e.nextElementSibling.style.color="red")
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="1" value="Bike" data-myname="">
<label for="vehicle1"> 1</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="Car">
<label for="vehicle2"> 2</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" value="Boat" checked>
<label for="vehicle3"> 3</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" value="Boat"  data-myname="">
<label for="vehicle3"> 4</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" value="Boat">
<label for="vehicle3"> 5</label><br>
```

Comment: Thank you... Though I could not use `document.querySelectorAll` directly due to some other binding factors, I was able to create the filter based on your solution. Marking as accepted answer